# Can't select any object in edit mode 2.9

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, object-mode

In edit mode I can only select the object I click in "object mode". When I click on others objects nothing happening. I always have to switch in object mode if I want to select another object and then go back to edit mode for edit the object.

Comment: If you want to be able to edit more than one _Object_ in edit mode, you must select all the objects you want to edit (In object mode) before entering edit mode.

Comment: Thank you! it was that easy! I feel kinda stupid

Comment: Don't worry, it's not stupid - Before version 2.8 you could only select and edit one object at a time. I still model this way (for the most part) out of habit.